# Cat the content of a file with specific content in it,outside the route

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to show the content of a .log file but only on the contents that have a certain information in it.

For example: if the file has string "rejection 20" on it's content, i want to see the content of that file with a string "rejection 20" in it

The problem is also that i need to access the .log file from outside the folder where it is

I tried to get into the route with a find and then apply the cat, and grep what i want

```
#! /bin/bash

find . /opt/logs/files.local/example.log -exec cat -b example.log {} \; | grep 48=login
```

But it brings back a lot of random information

Is there a way i can cat information of the logs to show me what i need?

Comment: `grep -n login example.log` Does that work for you?

Comment: Better add sample input/expected output...

Comment: Why is `grep '48-login'  /opt/logs/files.local/example.log` not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request, You want to see the whole file if contains a token, not just the token or the line with the token.

So, write a function like this:

```bash
search_and_print() {
    token="$1"
    filename="$2
    grep "$token" "$filename" >/dev/null && cat "$filename";
}
```

You could simplify by:

```bash
search_and_print() {
    grep "$1" "$2" >/dev/null && cat "$2";
}
```

Search files with `find` a call the function of them:

```bash
find /the/1st/directory /the/2nd/directory -name "pattern.log" -print0 \
| while read -r -d '' filename; do \
    search_and_print 'the_token_to_search' "$filename"; \
  done
```

Explanations:

- the `find` command searches in the named directories and subdirectories for files that match the pattern (`-name` option)

  - all found files are not separated by a new line (the default behaviour) but with a null character (`-print0` option)
- The `while` loop works on the whole result of the `find` command until the `read` command does not work anymore
- The `read` command uses the null character as separator of elements (`-d ''`, empty string for the `-d` option)

  - `-r` option ignores the behaviour of backslash characters in read string
  - The read string is stored in `filename` variable

One line:

```bash
search_and_print() { grep "$1" "$2" >/dev/null && cat "$2"; }; find /the/1st/directory /the/2nd/directory -name "pattern.log" -print0 | while read -r -d '' filename; do search_and_print 'the_token_to_search' "$filename"; done
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it's returning a lot of info. It is basically what you said but to make it simpler, If i do a cat directly in the file i want, for example a cat -A file.log | grep "token"    brings exactly what i want. But i want to do this from outside of the directory

Comment: Ok, just replace the content of `search_and_print` function with `cat -A "$2" | grep "$1"`

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! now it returns the content with the token in it.  Can you please tell me what this part does? read -r -d '' filename;   just for knowledge

Comment: See explanations in my updated answer